# WKWebView not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to load content from a website using WKWebView from a certain website but I end up with a white page. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url:url)

        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: With your code, I was able to load the web view.

Comment: Can I ask you what version of xcode are you using ?

Comment: Xcode 9.3, iOS 11.3.

Comment: Interesting. I am running the same versions but I end up with a blank white screen

Comment: Make sure your IBOutlet is connected properly or disconnect and connect again.

Comment: I checked it does not work thanks anyway

Comment: @Ahmed, Have you fixed issue ?

Comment: @SagarChauhan no there seem to be a problem I tried the deprecated webview it works but wkwebview dont work

Comment: Can you share code ?

Comment: the code is already shared. Do you mean the deprecated one ?

Comment: Means, With storyboard and view controller.

Comment: @SagarChauhan you can download it from github https://github.com/sengab87/webKitView.git

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// Add plist file 
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>google.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

```
 if WKWebView don't not support then declare .m file below code:



#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WebScannerViewController()
{

 WKWebView *webView;

}

 @end

 @implementation WebScannerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

 {

[super viewDidLoad];
webView.hidden=YES;

webView.UIDelegate = self;
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
self.loadingSign.hidden = NO;

 webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 94, Width, Height-128);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set the viewController as the navigationDelegate of the webview

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```